# How do I read a text file stored in the Genymotion sdcard path in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio, genymotion

I've answered my own question after doing some research. I was originally attempting to find the .txt file that I had stored in the emulator (/sdcard/emulated/0/info.txt). Instead of directing the File there, you should first create an sdcard file (see below) to access the external storage directory, and then search for your file inside of it.

Another thing I had failed to do was to set the text in the textview. `buildingsTxt.setText(readTxt());` So make sure you add a line like this in your onCreate() method.

**SOLUTION:**

```
public class Reader extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String readTxt(){
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"info.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String [] tokens = line.split(":");
                String code = tokens[0];
                String name = tokens[1];
                String lat = tokens[2];
                String longi = tokens[3];

                text.append(code);
                text.append('\n');
                text.append(name);
                text.append('\n');
                text.append("Latitude: " + lat);
                text.append('\n');
                text.append("Longitude: " + longi);
                text.append('\n');
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        TextView buildingsTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        buildingsTxt.setText(readTxt());
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Is there file by that path?

Comment: Yeah the file is definitely there. When I run the app I just get a blank activity screen.

Comment: I considered creating a raw resource file to get around the issue but then that defeats the purpose of using the sdcard feature

Comment: Start with reading logcat please and post it here.

Comment: You even write in logcat - "Log.i("rs", "rs=" + rs);". But what you given not related to your code.

Comment: Admittedly, I pulled this from an example I found online and adapted it for something else I wanted to test out.